# update images in Admin controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to update users' images and I'm thinking of a way to give admins the ability of updating only one image or both images or none for the user (profile image and license image). However, I'm getting an error that the images are null. 
here is my editing Action in the admin controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditDriver(int id)
        {
            DriversTier tier = new DriversTier();
            DriversModel driver = tier.getDriverByID(id);
            WebImage image = new WebImage();
            GetProfileImage(image.driverId);
            GetLicenseImage(image.driverId);


            return View(driver);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditDriver(DriversModel driver, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
        {
            if (images!= null) { 
            var profileImg = images.ElementAt(0);
            var licenseImg = images.ElementAt(1);
                if (profileImg== null && profileImg.ContentLength<0 && licenseImg != null && licenseImg.ContentLength >0)
                {

                    driver.licenseImgType = licenseImg.ContentType;
                    string fileName = licenseImg.FileName;
                    string pattern = @"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";

                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                    //Get the length of the image in bytes and create that array
                    driver.licenseImg = new byte[licenseImg.ContentLength];

                    //fill the array of bytes with the image data
                    licenseImg.InputStream.Read(driver.licenseImg, 0, licenseImg.ContentLength);

                    //Need to do model state checking here, provided some code for that already

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    profileImg = null;


                }else
                {
                    return null;
                }

                //First check the first Image
                if (profileImg != null && profileImg.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                driver.profileImgType = profileImg.ContentType;
                string fileName = profileImg.FileName;

                string pattern = @"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";

                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                //Get the length of the image in bytes and create that array
                driver.profileImg = new byte[profileImg.ContentLength];

                //fill the array of bytes with the image data
                profileImg.InputStream.Read(driver.profileImg, 0, profileImg.ContentLength);

                //Need to do model state checking here, provided some code for that already

                ModelState.Clear();

            }

                if (licenseImg==null && profileImg!= null && profileImg.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    driver.profileImgType = profileImg.ContentType;
                    string fileName = profileImg.FileName;
                    string pattern = @"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";

                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                    //Get the length of the image in bytes and create that array
                    driver.profileImg = new byte[profileImg.ContentLength];

                    //fill the array of bytes with the image data
                    profileImg.InputStream.Read(driver.profileImg, 0, profileImg.ContentLength);

                    //Need to do model state checking here, provided some code for that already

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    licenseImg = null;
                }else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            if (licenseImg != null && licenseImg.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                driver.licenseImgType = licenseImg.ContentType;
                string fileName = licenseImg.FileName;
                string pattern = @"([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)";

                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

                //Get the length of the image in bytes and create that array
                driver.licenseImg = new byte[licenseImg.ContentLength];

                //fill the array of bytes with the image data
                licenseImg.InputStream.Read(driver.licenseImg, 0, licenseImg.ContentLength);

                //Need to do model state checking here, provided some code for that already

                ModelState.Clear();

            }
            }
            if (images== null)
            {
                GetProfileImage(driver.driverId);
                GetLicenseImage(driver.driverId);
            }

            DriversTier tier = new DriversTier();
           // WebImage image = tier.getProfileImg(id);

            tier.UpdateDrivers(driver);


            return RedirectToAction("DisplayDrivers/" + driver.driverId);
        }
```

How would I allow images to be null or one of them in this case? 
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is causing your issue, but it looks like you have an extra closing curly brace in your code:

```
ModelState.Clear();

            }
            }   <--- extra closing curly brace?
            if (images== null)
```